# Como Adicionar um "overflow:scroll;" na lateral de um 'datalist' extenso

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma barra de pesquisas type="text" junto a um datalist, porém não estou tendo sucesso ao adicionar uma barra de rolagem na lateral do conteúdo exibido, pois quanto mais adicionamos nomes no 'option value="" mais extenso fica o quadro de listas exibido, por conta disso eu pretendo adicionar um overflow:; nesse elemento. Tem alguma possibilidade de inserir um overflow:; nesse datalist ?

```css
.bt{ position:relative; 
top:11px; 
font-size:16px; 
height:36px; 
font-weight:bold; 
width:36px; 
outline:none; 
background-image:url(../BT/Lupa.jpg); 
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
background-position:1px; 
background-size:32px 32px; 
border-radius:10px; 
border:1px solid  #06F; 
cursor:pointer; 
}
.bt:hover{ box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000000;
}
.br{ height:30px; 
position:relative; 
left:5px; 
font-weight:bold;
border: 2px solid #06F; 
border-radius:30px; 
outline:none;
}
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  background-color: transparent;
}

/*Não funciona!*/
datalist { height: 50px; 
position: relative; 
overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<form>

<input list="ctg" type="text" class="br" oninput="myfunction()" placeholder="Pesquisar..." >

<datalist id="ctg" class="dt">

   <option value="HTML-0"><a href="Checkbox buttons checkeds.html"></a></option>
   <option value="HTML-1"><a href="Checkbox buttons checkeds.html"></a></option>
   <option value="HTML-2"><a href="Checkbox buttons checkeds.html"></a></option>
   <option value="HTML-3"><a href="Checkbox buttons checkeds.html"></a></option>
   <option value="HTML-4"><a href="Checkbox buttons checkeds.html"></a></option>
   <option value="HTML-5"><a href="Checkbox buttons checkeds.html"></a></option>
   <option value="HTML-6"><a href="Checkbox buttons checkeds.html"></a></option>

</datalist>

<input type="submit" id="ctg" class="bt" value=""/>

</form>
```

Comment: Não dá pra usar um `<textarea>` na busca e um `<div>` com `overflow-y`?

Comment: Esse <textarea> eu insiro no lugar do <option> ?

Comment: Não, eu tinha pensado que a caixa de texto da busca tava ficando apertada, também. Coloca o `<div style="overflow-y: scroll">` cercando as `<options>`, por favor.

Comment: Funciona não, parece que aquele quadro com as lista é inalterável, eu acho que deve ter algum -webkit-  para edita-lo

Comment: Até você comentar sobre isso, eu nem sabia que existia essa tag `<datalist>`. Deve ter algum xunxo pra resolver isso!

Comment: Tem que ser Datalist ou pode ser um Select com os Options?

Comment: Eu estou usando um Js junto com o css, seria melhor um datalist, mas caso der com select, talvez eu consiga fazer as alterações no Js mudando a referencia

Comment: Mas eu queria muito utilizar uma barra de rolagem, pra essa bendita lista

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788245/how-can-i-limit-the-visible-options-in-an-html-select-dropdown

Comment: Não dá pra cercar, em vez de com `<datalist>`, cercar as `<option>`s com `<select>`?

Comment: Acabei de fazer aqui, e não deu certo, aconteceu uma especie de conflito com os href=""; parece que quando adiciona links a barra comprimi e fica vertical, horrível!! kkkk

Comment: Não tem jeito não, o meu Javascript precisa de um 'input' para funcionar junto com os links, e adicionando um select enrola tudo. O bom é que eu descobri um scrollzinho básico através do 'select' que no caso eu não tinha conhecimento ainda desse conteúdo

Answer (score 0):

Amigo nada que vc tente em questão de **CSS** ira funcionar com este elemento, pois cada navegador define seu próprio estilo para este tipo de elemento. Veja no código  CSS as partes comentadas.

```css
.bt{ position:relative; 
top:11px; 
font-size:16px; 
height:36px; 
font-weight:bold; 
width:36px; 
outline:none; 
background-image:url(../BT/Lupa.jpg); 
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
background-position:1px; 
background-size:32px 32px; 
border-radius:10px; 
border:1px solid  #06F; 
cursor:pointer; 
}
.bt:hover{ box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000000;
}
.br{ height:30px; 
position:relative; 
left:5px; 
font-weight:bold;
border: 2px solid #06F; 
border-radius:30px; 
outline:none;
}
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  background-color: transparent;
}

/*Não funciona!*/
datalist { 
height: 1000px !important;            /*veja aqui*/
position: relative !important; 
overflow-y: scroll !important;        /*veja aqui*/
background-color: red !important;     /*veja aqui*/
}
```

```html
<form>

  <input list="ctg" type="text" class="br" oninput="myfunction()" placeholder="Pesquisar..." >

    <datalist id="ctg" class="dt">

   <option value="HTML-0"><a href="Checkbox buttons checkeds.html"></a></option>
   <option value="HTML-1"><a href="Checkbox buttons checkeds.html"></a></option>
   <option value="HTML-2"><a href="Checkbox buttons checkeds.html"></a></option>
   <option value="HTML-3"><a href="Checkbox buttons checkeds.html"></a></option>
   <option value="HTML-4"><a href="Checkbox buttons checkeds.html"></a></option>
   <option value="HTML-5"><a href="Checkbox buttons checkeds.html"></a></option>
   <option value="HTML-6"><a href="Checkbox buttons checkeds.html"></a></option>

  </datalist>

 <input type="submit" id="ctg" class="bt" value=""/>

</form>
```

**OBS:** Como referência esta resposta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693482/is-there-a-way-to-apply-a-css-style-on-html5-datalist-options) no site em inglês.

Comment: Eu estou usando o Chrome

Comment: Sim, pois é, ele renderiza da maneira dele este elemento, não dá para estilizá-lo, infelizmente.